# No Jquery intellisense Support for Visual Studio 2008

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I have Visual Studio 2008 Pro. SP1 and Hotfix

> KB958502 - JScript Editor support for
>   “-vsdoc.js” IntelliSense doc. files

installed, but still no intellisense Support is available in VS2008.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.js">
$("#TextBox1").
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `jquery-1.4.1.js` , `jquery-1.4.1.min.js` and `jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc` insteated of version 1.6.1 in vs2008

Comment: This makes zero sense as an accepted answer.  Just b/c we use VS2008, we can't use 1.6.1?  Why?

Answer (score 5):

I'm NOT sure but shouldn't a  tag should have EITHER a 'src' or inline content but not both?

Your code has them both.
Maybe this would work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#TextBox1").
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery Intellisense in VS 2008](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx) - Take a look at the comments...

Make sure that this path is correct: `src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.js"`

Download and try adding the vsdoc file too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.1-vsdoc.js" />
```

You're referencing the jQuery script file and at the same time you're trying to write code within that script code block. This isn't possible I think. I at least have never tried this way.

Do this way instead (this should work):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1-vsdoc.js" />

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#TextBox1").

</script>
```

Comment: @jams: 1st - try restarting Visual Studio. If this doesn't solve your problem... 2nd - try restarting your computer. Try these steps and get back.

Comment: @jams: try adding `../../` before the script path as shown in my answer.

Comment: I have tried it all things which you have mentioned still not working

Comment: @jams: now the hard way... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307555/vs2008-jquery-intellisense-not-working-jquery-1-4-1-js + http://www.devcurry.com/2009/05/visual-studio-2008-intellisense-for.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a -vsdoc.js for 1.6.1?  I didn't think one was available past 1.4.1 which is available here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

So VS presumably won't find it automatically if you're referencing 1.6.1.  You could rename the 1.4.1 to 1.6.1 and make sure it's in the same path.

Alternatively you can reference the vsdoc directly using the // reference tags, as explained in the Scott Gu article.